# Hiding the extension url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to hide the extension part of Url and display only the website name for all the actions we do in MVC.

Example:
Actual Url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
-- **Questions** is controller and **ask** is the action method here.

Desired Url: https://stackoverflow.com/

I know we could achieve this by giving default values in Routes.config. In case if we want to same for all controllers and actions without defining default values for each one, **is there a way to achieve this dynamically.**

Comment: How would you know what URL the user is accessing if you always use the same URL?

Comment: Hey Pranb Thanks for ur time.... requirement is to hide the url displayed to the user in backend routing should handle the pointing to right action and controller.

Comment: if you have one controller, and one action that could make sense what you are asking for, but if you have  more than one controller, how you could know which controller you want to use, you need to send some information, so the server could know what you are looking for, right ?

Comment: Agreed, but that is the requirement i have got :(

Comment: how the server could know what you looking for? you have to send some information , either in url, header or the body of the request. if you are sending the action name and the controller name somehow in the request, then I believe there could be a way

Answer (score 0):

Unless you switch to using something like Angular to keep track of your user's status, the only option I see available is to make everything a get variable or set their status in the session, and try reading it in the main controller, using a switch statement to call whatever parts of code you need. That's not a recommended development pattern, though.